# how to store an nsmutablearray data into nsstring variable using objective c

Tags: ios

HERE NSMutableArray data that I want to store into five  nsstring variables are:** one for id another for money ,another for packaged and last for type by for loop.

```
   id money package  type
   1   $1   1,020MB  Somnet
   2.  $2   2,040MB  Somnet
   3  $3    3,060MB  Somnet
   4  $4    4,080MB Somnet
   5  $5    5,100MB somnet
```

please help me how to solve this.

Comment: Do you want to save the four field's value(index wise) in each single string ??

Comment: yes I want to save these four fields in NSMutableArray   into four different variables please help how to done this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
   NSString *id ;
   NSString *money ;
   NSString *pakege ;
   NSString *item ;



  for (int i = 0; i < [yourArray count]; i++) {
         if (i == 0) {
             id = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];

                  }
          if (i == 1) {
               money = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];

                     }
          if (i == 2) {
                     pakage = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];

                     }
           if (i == 3) {
                     item = [yourArray objectAtIndex:i];

                     }

                     }
```

Comment: This is good but I used one NSMutableArray variable only all these value is stored this NSMutableArray and I want to store four different variable from my NSMutableArray to new  four variables by for loop.

Comment: are you using dictionary??  for storing that id, money , packegae, type, please send me your NSMutableArray

Comment: No I am not please help me and give simple example that solves my problem .I am new this objective c

Comment: send me your NSMutableArray i will send the perfect Answer

Comment: not empty NSMutableArray send with values how can you stored that id and money and type and packages, this question is not correct format

Comment: these returned from api                                                                                -(void)proxydidFinishLoadingData:(id)data InMethod:(NSString*)method
{
    
    if ([method isEqualToString:@"getmobiledata"]){
        mobile = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableDictionary * defaultDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [defaultDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] options:0 error:nil]];
        [mobile addObject:[defaultDict objectForKey:@"data"]];
    }
}

Comment: Mr. Pramod Reddy help me my problem

Comment: you are getting API response in the form of Dictionary, and you stored the NSMutableArray ok then one thing i should know in the zero index you getting id and first index getting money and second package and third type is it correct

Comment: yes it is and I need all these value to be stored into four different variables  first variable for zero index  another for first index ,another for package and last for type by using for loop. please help me how to solve this

Comment: k i wil send example related

Comment: above edited code check it once its like example ..hope it can help you